# Need lookup filter that filters a date against today or date stored in a formula field

Tags: lookup-filter

I have a lookup field in the quote line item standard object.  It is a lookup field to a custom object that has a field that is an expiration date.

I need to be able to filter the lookup so that it does not return any record that has an expiration date that has passed (it's < today's date).  Unfortunately neither TODAY nor formula fields are supported in lookup field filters.  Is there a workaround for this?

I've looked at http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/08/12/roll-your-own-salesforce-lookup-popup-window/ but it says that workaround is for VF pages, not for standard page layouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider a writeable `Is_Active__c` checkbox field, which you can then turn to false using a `Time Based Workflow Rule`. That way, you should be able to include the field in your filter, but still have it indicate whether or not the expiration date has passed.

Comment: Adrian: Thank you! I've never used a time-based workflow rule before - that's the solution I need.  Thank you!